# Using a Main Surge Protector for only branching out other surge protectors

Tags: current, power-electronics, surge-protection

Whenever I try to find information about this question it always says that it is not good to plug in a surge protector into a surge protector because you can overload or overheat the protector or circuit.

I was wondering is it perfectly fine to do if you do not overload the surge protector?

High rated surge protector 15a with 4000 joule protection has only other surge protectors plugged into it not bother electronics just for the purposes of charging that higher joule protection.

Additionally I read up and it states that there is an increase in protection if two surge protectors are plugged into each other. Is this true?

Lastly, the worse case I have in my configuration is a main surge protector with a 15a cable (that serves as the main one) that has a smaller surge protector and then an extension cord, could this power a 50 inch tv and baby monitor camera or will it not have enough power? It is under 50 feet of surge protector/extension. Someone on another forum said it might lose current and under-power the tv, damaging it.

The main question is, is this configuration safe and will it degrade any of my parts or not provide enough power in regards to my tv and camera as mentioned above? Will it cause some kind of fluctuation if it is not overloaded?

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to S. Binder's answer to just provide my experience with multiple surge protectors:

### Observations:

1. A surge protector is also often viewed as an outlet strip or splitter — an easy way to get more outlets out of one.
2. Most modern protectors are reasonably good at doing what they're supposed to: protect. They include circuit breakers which are meant to limit how much power they supply.
3. With the plethora of small personal devices these days, in an office environment, I generally see surge protectors used to provide outlets for USB chargers, computers, monitors, network equipment, desk lamps, and so on. Most of these are low power devices, and even with every outlet on a surge protector occupied, the total power is well within safe limits.
4. All of that said, when someone plugs a 1500 watt space heater into the surge protector, it eventually (if not immediately) trips the breaker. Most basic surge protectors are only rated for 15A, which at 120V equates to 1800 watts. With other devices connected, a single heater will usually push things above the protector's limits.
5. In theory, a surge protector daisy-chained into one or more other surge protectors *increases* protection, because multiple circuit breakers are now involved. However...

### Problems:

1. Casually, people don't think about total power on a given circuit. Multiple surge protectors offer "more outlets!" to the random passerby. This can result in people adding additional items to a circuit that may already be close to its limit. This can be dangerous if...
2. Surge protectors (or just "multiple outlet strips"), like anything else, can fail. If it has no circuit breaker, or is faulty, that can be the precursor to disaster ranging from a melted device to a burned-down building.
3. Because of the above two problems, most commercial or industrial areas will not allow them to be serially connected. (Inspectors will cite you.) It's not because of being intrinsically unsafe, it's that it invites improper loads to occur, which then *tests* the safety devices. The local fire marshal prefers situations where safety devices are not tested and not relied upon. Apply the same rules at home and don't "test" your homeowners or renters insurance.

Comment: When referring to a faulty or non existent circuit breaker you are referring to a circuit break in a home electrical panel being faulty or not existent? You are not referring to a circuit breaker in a surge protector? This is regards to understanding problem 2.

Comment: I am referring to the breakers in the surge protectors. The home or business circuit breaker should _always_ be present. The surge protector breakers are redundant. For example, if the home breaker is 20A, a surge protector breaker rated at 15A should trip first, and leave the home breaker untripped.

Answer (score 1):

I think the bigger issue is total current draw of the circuit.  As a general rule you shouldn't plug a power strip into another power strip because someone could overload the capacity of the circuit / power strip if they didn't know what they were doing.  In a commercial setting you would probably even fail an inspection by the local fire department if they saw you doing that.

to your point, purely surge protection would probably be increased by adding more surge suppressors in series.